# Check if a database table contains any rows

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin

I'm loading data into a form with 3 `Entry` controls.

The object I am using for this is called `mySettings`, which is an object of `SystemSettings`, a class and database table in my `SQLite` database.

So far I have this code, and it works as is.

```
var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);

Entry txtServer;
txtServer = new Entry { FontSize = 10 };
controlGrid.Children.Add(txtServer, 2, 0);
Grid.SetColumnSpan(txtServer, 4);

SystemSettings mySettings;
mySettings = db.Get<SystemSettings>(0);
txtServer.Text = mySettings.FTPServer;
```

However, I need to check whether `SystemSettings` contains any rows in the table before I load values in.

I've seen a few guides online.

Some say use something along the lines of

```
SQLiteCommand cmd;
cmd = new SQLiteCommand(db);

...

int result = Convert.ToInt32(db.ExecuteScalar)
```

However, I get an error there saying

> SQLiteCommand does not contain any method containing x parameters

no matter how many I pass in (0 or more).

There also doesn't appear to be a method as part of `db.`

So how can I check whether `SystemSettings` contains any rows, before trying to use data that doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is to get the first row in you `SystemSettings` table if any:
You should therefore execute the following Sql Statement (or something similar) and check if a result is returned:

```
Select * from SystemSettings LIMIT 1;
```

You can execute the query and check the result like this:

```
public bool DoesTableContainRows(string tableName, SQLiteConnection connection)
{
    var command = new SQLiteCommand($"Select * from {tableName } LIMIT 1;", connection);
    var resultReader = command.ExecuteReader();
    // check whether or not a row was returned
    bool containRows = resultReader.Read();
    resultReader.Close();
    return containRows;
}
```

**Edit:**
Shows how to check if a table contains rows using .NET and Microsoft.Data.Sqlite including better disposing of resources.

```
public bool DoesTableContainRows(string tableName, SqliteConnection connection)
{
    using (var command = new SqliteCommand($"Select * from {tableName } LIMIT 1;", connection))
    {
        using (var resultReader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
             // check whether or not a row was returned
             bool containRows = resultReader.Read();
             resultReader.Close();
             return containRows;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "SQLiteCommand does not contain a constructor that takes 2 methods", as well as "SQLiteCommand does not contain a definition for ExecuteReader and no extension ExectuteReader accepting a first argument type of SQLiteCommand could be found"

Comment: I'm using System.Data.SQLite.Core (1.0.109.1), but you are probably using .NET instead of .NET Core i assume? If this is the case I will update my answer tonight to reflect your development environment

Comment: I believe so, yes.

Comment: @Harambe I updated my answer to use .NET see the **Edit** section. Please note that I use the nuget package _Microsoft.Data.Sqlite_ as can be found [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SQLite/)

Answer (score 1):

The pattern below should work. The .ExecuteScalar() method is actually on the command and not the connection.

```
    int count;
    using (SQLiteConnection db = new SQLiteConnection("MY_CXN_STRING"))
    using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SystemSettings"))
    {
        db.Open();
        count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        db.Close();
    }
bool hasRows = count != 0;
```

Comment: 'SQLiteCommand': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable' & second error 'The type arguments for SQLiteCommand.ExecuteScalar<T>() cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments implicitly'.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want to clear

```
SystemSettings
```

Try just running a query that returns nothing against the database. For instance:

```
SystemSettings = $"SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COLUMN_NAME IS 'INVALID_EXPRESSIONdjeiq48724rufnjdrandom stuff'";
```

Not the most elegant solution by any means, but it works.